# Composer Gives Error, "Class Not Found"

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php, autoloader, psr-4

I'm using Windows 10. After making a folder `src` in the root directory I created two files in it.

Directory Structure (Before running `composer install`):

```
│
├── composer.json
├── run.php
│
└── src
     ├── childclass.php
     └── parentclass.php
```

Two files in the root directory:

composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "myvendor/mypackage",
    "description": "nothing",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Omar Tariq",
            "email": "XXXXX@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {},
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "myns\\": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

run.php:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use myns\childclass as childclass;

$childclass = new childclass();
$childclass->abc();
```

Two files in the src folder:

childclass.php:

```
<?php

require_once 'parentclass.php';

use myns\parentclass as parentclass;

class childclass extends parentclass
{
    public function abc()
    {
        echo 'hello world';
    }
}
```

parentclass.php:

```
<?php

namespace myns;

abstract class parentclass
{
    abstract public function abc();
}
```

Directory structure after running `composer install`:

```
│
├── composer.json
├── run.php
│
├── src
│    ├── childclass.php
│    └── parentclass.php
│
└── vendor
     ├── autoload.php
     │
     └── composer
          ├── autoload_classmap.php
          ├── autoload_namespaces.php
          ├── autoload_psr4.php
          ├── autoload_real.php
          ├── ClassLoader.php
          ├── installed.json
          └── LICENSE
```

Now, when I run:

```
php run.php
```

I get this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'myns\childclass' not found in C:\wamp...\run.php on line 7

Comment: Maybe it's because you are missing `namespace myns;` in your child class?

Comment: What @BrianGlaz said, also: You shouldn't need the require_once in your child class at all - that's what the autoloader is for.

Comment: @BrianGlaz Yes, that's correct. It resolved my problem. Thanks for quick response :-)

Comment: @ccKep That's great. I really didn't know that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `composer.json` you defined that for `src` folder you use `myns` namespace, so in your `childclass.php` you should use

```
namespace myns;
```

It's also unnecessary to add:

```
require_once 'parentclass.php';
```

or

```
use myns\parentclass as parentclass;
```

so your childclass.php should look like this:

```
<?php

namespace myns;

class childclass extends parentclass
{
    public function abc()
    {
        echo 'hello world';
    }
}
```

In addition in `run.php` file you might replace:

```
use myns\childclass as childclass;
```

into

```
use myns\childclass;
```

You don't need to use `as` if you don't want to use other name for class.

You should also consider using namespaces with capital letter (Studly caps) and the same for classes. Instead of `myns` use `MyNs`, instead of `parentclass` use `ParentClass`. You should look at [PSR-1 coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/) and [PSR-2 coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) to follow best coding practises.

Comment: great answer! Would you be able to help me on my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39533795/php-and-composer-why-am-i-getting-a-class-error-in-file-in-wordpress-theme-fold