# How To Make Composer (PSR-4) To Work With ".class.php" Extension?

Tags: php, composer-php

I've been facing a lot of problem with "Class Not Found" error. But recently I recognized the original problem. My previous two questions regarding the issue:-

[Composer Gives Error, "Class Not Found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33289135/composer-gives-error-class-not-found)

[PHP Composer PSR-4 Autoloading And Sub-Namespaces, Class Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33290004/php-composer-psr-4-autoloading-and-sub-namespaces-class-not-found)

I'm interested in working with classes having extension `class.php`, e.g. `parent.class.php` and `child.class.php`. But composer doesn't seem to recognize these files and "Class Not Found" error is displayed. The problem is resolved if I use simple .php extension (`child.php` and `parent.php`).

I was wondering if it is possible to make composer work with `.class.php` extension for my php class files?

Comment: That's how [PSR-4 is meant to be](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/): *The terminating class name corresponds to a file name ending in .php. The file name MUST match the case of the terminating class name.*

Comment: I suggest simply not to use those extensions. It's legacy convention from PHP4. No one uses this style anymore. Nowadays, you can recognize a file holding a class by it's first letter beeing uppercase.

Comment: @DanFromGermany If I've to upgrade my knowledge to latest conventions and standards of PHP then where should I look for?

Comment: The standards recommendation in PHP is hosted at http://www.php-fig.org/ - note that this isn't the only effort to standardize things, nor the only way to start proposing standards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want your code to be PSR-4 compliant, then you **MUST** have your filenames in the format `classname.php`.

From the PSR-4 spec:

> The terminating class name corresponds to a file name ending in .php. The file name MUST match the case of the terminating class name.

(http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/)

So if you're sticking with PSR-4 then the answer is that you can't use your `.class.php` filenames. Just change the filenames and the problem will be solved.

If you absolutely have to keep the existing filenames for some reason, then you will need to work around it by writing your own autoloader function or just include them manually the old-school way. (But remember that you won't be conforming to PSR-4 if you do this)