# Composer autoload - load class from parent directory

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, psr-4

I'm currently working on a Laravel project that needs to access classes from its parent directory.

composer.json > PSR-4:

```
    "psr-4": {
        ...
        "ModuleA\\": "../ModuleA/baseObjects",
        "ModuleB\\": "../ModuleB/baseObjects"
    }
```

Example file structure:

```
/var/www
 +- /xxx (project)
     +- /ModuleA
        +- /baseObjects
            - configClass.inc
     +- /ModuleB
        +- /baseObjects
            - configClass.inc
     +- /laravel
        - composer.json
```

I run `composer dump-autoload` but the project still can't find `ModuleA\configClass` neither `ModuleB\configClass`.

Furthermore, inside my `autoload_psr4.php`, the above gets referenced as following:

```
'MobuleA\\' => array($baseDir . '/../MobuleA/baseObjects')
'MobuleB\\' => array($baseDir . '/../MobuleB/baseObjects')
```

Comment: try  "": "src(main folder i guess its)/" no need to initialize the modules just add folder and /

Answer (score 4):

PSR-4 requires the loaded files to have a namespaced class, and the namespace structure has to match the directory structure, relative to the "base directory" defined in the configuration (http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/).

So, in file `/var/xxx/ModuleA/baseObjects/configClass.inc` should be the class

```
namespace ModuleA\baseObjects;

class configClass {
    ...
}
```

Then in `var/www/laravel/composer.json` you could have

```
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "ModuleA\\": "../ModuleA"
    }
```

Which means: "directory `../ModuleA` should be the root for `ModuleA` namespace, then follow subnamespaces by matching subdirectories from there".

Answer (score 3):

Use classmap autoload will solve this problem.

```
{
...
"autoload": {
        "classmap": ["ModuleA/", "ModuleB/"]
    }
}
```

It could be used with PSR-4

```
{
    ...
    "autoload": {
            "psr-4": { 
                "Acme\\": "src/Acme/"
            },
            "classmap": ["ModuleA/", "ModuleB/"]
        }
    }
```

Ref: https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#classmap

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're experiencing is not related to parent directories. In fact, your Composer.json autoload configuration is correct for your directory structure.

The problem is the `.inc` file extension, which is incompatible with the PSR-4 specification. More info here: [How To Make Composer (PSR-4) To Work With ".class.php" Extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33298164/how-to-make-composer-psr-4-to-work-with-class-php-extension)

If you cannot update your source code to match the PSR-4 spec, you can use [Class Mapping](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#classmap):

> The classmap references are all combined, during install/update, into a single key => value array which may be found in the generated file `vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php`. This map is built by scanning for classes in all `.php` and `.inc` files in the given directories/files.
>
> You can use the classmap generation support to define autoloading for all libraries that do not follow PSR-0/4. To configure this you specify all directories or files to search for classes.

So your config might look like:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "../ModuleA/baseObjects",
        "../ModuleB/baseObjects"
    ]
}
```

Remember, if you use class mapping, you'll need to run `composer dump-autoload` any time you change `composer.json`, add a class, modify a class' name/filename/path, etc.

**Extra:** as pointed out by @alepeino, using [autoloader optimization](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/autoloader-optimization.md) will generate a class map from any PSR-0 and PSR-4 autoload definitions, using the same underlying code that `classmap` autoload uses. This will "allow" you to use PSR-4 autoloader and the `.inc` extension. This will still require you to run `composer dump-autoload --optimize` every time you make a file change, though, just like classmap.

Best recommendation: change your source code to follow PSR-4 specifications, and use the `.php` extension.

Next best if you can't do that: use `classmap` for autoloading.

Comment: I thought so I first, so I tried it, and found that although the PSR-4 specification says the file extension "MUST" be ".php", composer actually loaded a ".inc" correctly.

Comment: I'd like to see the code you used tested for testing. I did a basic PSR-4 set up matching the directory structure in question, and then changed one of the class extensions to .inc and it could no longer be found. The [autoloader explicitly sets the extension](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/e42e1156d51ca5494b058b1a7b480bc703c4f57a/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassLoader.php#L351). Perhaps a difference in Composer version?

Comment: It turns out I did my first test in a Laravel project, then again tried in a bare new ad-hoc project and wouldn't work. My original composer.json had `optimize-autoloader` on. See https://github.com/alepeino/composer-optimize

Comment: Aha! Looking at Composer's source again, `optimize-autoloader` and equivalent end up running the class mapper across all PSR-0 & PSR-4 directories, which will look for `.inc` extension files.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28285201/4776831) you can add it in the index.php file:

```
$loader = require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$loader->add('Namespace\\Somewhere\\Else\\', __DIR__);
$loader->add('Namespace\\Somewhere\\Else2\\', '/var/www/html/xxx');
```

Answer (score -1):

try it：

```
"psr-4": {
        ...
        "ModuleA\\": "ModuleA/baseObjects",
        "ModuleB\\": "ModuleB/baseObjects"
 }
```

Comment: It doesn't work, the code above attempts to find it in the current directory, I'm trying to access the parent directory.

Comment: Wrong answer, short explanation. Downvoted.